# Does AWS EKS fargate support istio?

Tags: istio, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

i am trying to deploy an app along with istio on eks fargate. But my pods remain in pending state.I want to know wheather AWS EKS fargate support istio.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running EKS Fargate only cluster, the answer is no.
The support of Fargate to ISTIO has been added to the roadmap since Jan 2020 however as for today, we still don't find any update yet, refer https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/682

The alternative option to ISTIO would be using AWS App Mesh.

Comment: So, if i use EKS nodegroup along with EKS fargate then is it possible?
1) deploying istio on node group
2) deploying app on fargate
does it work ?

Comment: Based on my understadning, for the application pods in the Istio service mesh, all traffic to/from the pods needs to go through the istio-proxy containers, Istio-proxy container needs NET_ADMIN to add the iptable rules which is still not possible at this moment.

Comment: The situation is the same in 2023. I'd suggest run EKS on EC2 instead